# i tried to insert data in a table but the data is not storing in the table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1039, 584)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.image_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 801, 511))
        self.image_label.setObjectName("image_label")
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.control_bt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 340, 93, 28))
        self.control_bt.setObjectName("control_bt")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 240, 158, 51))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 280, 158, 24))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(890, 310, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 230, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(910, 210, 55, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Face detection"))
        self.image_label.setText(_translate("Form", "                                                 FACE DETECTION"))
        self.control_bt.setText(_translate("Form", "Start"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "    Enter name of person"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "click to save"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "enter id"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.InsertData)``
    def InsertData(self):
        import sqlite3
        id=self.lineEdit.text()
        name=str(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        conn=sqlite3.connect('B.db')
        curs=conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO register (id,name) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+name+"');")
        print(id,name)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try change `curs.execute("INSERT INTO register (id,name) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+name+"');")` to `curs.execute("INSERT INTO register (id, name) VALUES (?,?)",(id, name))` ; 
        `conn.commit()`

Comment: @S.Nick   I tried its not working

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to import sqlite3 within your function again, then after your query commit your connection

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: i tried but its not working